# Issue after pip update to version 9.0.1 (on Ubuntu)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I have a python 2.7.12 installed on ubuntu 10.04. I have updated pip from 8.1.2 to the last version (9.0.1) but now when I run pip I get this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 233, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 251, in main
    timeout=min(5, options.timeout)) as session:
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 72, in _build_session
    insecure_hosts=options.trusted_hosts,
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 329, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 93, in user_agent
    from pip._vendor import distro
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 1050, in <module>
    _distro = LinuxDistribution()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 594, in __init__
    if include_lsb else {}
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 933, in _get_lsb_release_info
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(code, cmd, stdout)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'lsb_release -a' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Any ideas to solve this issue?

Comment: what is the command that you ran with `pip`?

Comment: `pip freeze`.
It returns the list of the installed packages and then the error trace above.

Comment: On Windows OS, I just upgraded from `8.1.2` to `9.0.1` using `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`. no issues observed with `pip freeze`. `lsb_release` is Linux specific module. please check the command individually `lsb_release -a` . reference https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.0.0/LSB-PDA/LSB-PDA/lsbrelease.html

Comment: if I execute the command `lsb_release` I get this error `ImportError: no module named lsb_release`.

I have, at the moment, "solved" downgrading the pip package following this procedure:  
`wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/e7/a8/7556133689add8d1a54c0b14aeff0acb03c64707ce100ecd53934da1aa13/pip-8.1.2.tar.gz --no-check-certificate`
`tar -xzvf pip-8.1.2.tar.gz`
`cd pip-8.1.2`
`sudo python setup.py install`

suggested on GitHub from Admed
[link](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3776)